# How to disable multiple keymaps with the same name?

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

I figured out how to disable a keymap by a unique name, but in this case, there are five different keymaps all named `wm.call_menu_pie`. Is there a way to iterate over it to disable all of them? or if I needed to just disable a specific one, is that possible?

This is the code that works:

```
bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.active.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['wm.call_menu_pie'].active = False
```

Answer (score 5):

**Call pie menu operator**

Firstly the name is the id (`bl_idname`) of the call pie menu operator.  The idname of the registered pie menu is passed as `name` property to the operator.

To call snap pie menu

```
bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_MT_snap_pie")
```

**Distinguish by the operator's name property**

[image]

To distinguish between them look at properties passed to the operator.

Test script to make a list of all pie menu short cuts in 3D view (from question).  Look for all the keymap items using this operator "wm.call_pie_menu" and populate  list with the name of the menu.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

wm = context.window_manager
active = wm.keyconfigs.active
view3d = active.keymaps["3D View"]

# using call menu

pies = [km.properties['name'] for name, km in view3d.keymap_items.items() if name == "wm.call_menu_pie"]

print(pies)
```

output

```
['VIEW3D_MT_view_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_snap_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_pivot_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_orientations_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_shading_pie']
```

**List Comprehension**

The list `pies` is created with list comprehension.  Recommend getting head around list comprehension.

To disable all, *Note `pies` is different here, it is being populated with the keymapitems, not the value of the operator name property*

[image]

```
pies = [km for name, km in view3d.keymap_items.items() if name == "wm.call_menu_pie"]

for pie in pies:
    pie.active = False
```

To disable all but snap

[image]

```
for pie in pies:
    pie.active = pie.properties['name'].endswith("snap_pie")
```

Toggle

[image]

```
for pie in pies:
    pie.active = not pie.active
```

All call pie menu keymap items in all active keymaps

Create a dictionary of all all the call pie menu operates in each keymap.

```
all_pies = {
        km.name : [
            kmi for name, kmi in km.keymap_items.items() 
            if name == "wm.call_menu_pie"
            #and kmi.properties['name'].endswith("foo"
        ] 
        for km in active.keymaps
        }

for name, pies in all_pies.items():
    if pies:
        print(name, [pie.properties['name'] for pie in pies])
```

Result

```
Grease Pencil Stroke Edit Mode ['GPENCIL_MT_snap_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Weight Paint ['VIEW3D_MT_wpaint_vgroup_lock_pie']
Object Mode ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Curve ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Sculpt ['VIEW3D_MT_sculpt_mask_edit_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_sculpt_face_sets_edit_pie']
Mesh ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Metaball ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Lattice ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Particle ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
3D View ['VIEW3D_MT_view_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_snap_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_pivot_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_orientations_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_shading_pie']
UV Editor ['IMAGE_MT_uvs_snap_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Mask Editing ['VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie']
Graph Editor ['GRAPH_MT_snap_pie', 'VIEW3D_MT_proportional_editing_falloff_pie', 'GRAPH_MT_pivot_pie']
Image ['IMAGE_MT_pivot_pie']
NLA Editor ['NLA_MT_snap_pie']
Clip ['CLIP_MT_tracking_pie', 'CLIP_MT_solving_pie', 'CLIP_MT_marker_pie', 'CLIP_MT_reconstruction_pie']
Clip Editor ['CLIP_MT_pivot_pie']
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response! I don't fully comprehend everything here, but will continue to study and learn.

I tried the script and it ran with no errors but didn't quite work. 

This is what I tried:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

wm = context.window_manager
active = wm.keyconfigs.active
view3d = active.keymaps["3D View"]

pies = [km for name, km in view3d.keymap_items.items() if name == "wm.call_menu_pie"]

for pie in pies:
    pie.active = False
```

Comment: Have added images re the result of same code. Make sure to mouse over the UI to show updated results.  Add print statements to debug, or test in python console.

Comment: Hmm .. how come I knew this was a batFiNGER answer when I was only 1/5 of the way down it? As usual, much more than a solution :)

Comment: @batFINGER you are awesome man. I will try again tomorrow, I am very grateful!